# dbunit cleaning certain data after test run

Tags: testing, dbunit

I am familiar with dbunit and its database operations:
 http://dbunit.sourceforge.net/components.html

Still I'm wondering is there any way to "clean" certain data from the database after the test is run? I mean I don't want to truncate or delete the whole table, only the rows test has inserted.

Answer (score 0):

I you are running test in a java environment with JUnit, for example, theoretically after each test the data comes back to the previous states, I mean, after make the test and insert data, this data are "deleted", like a roll back in a transaction.

Sometimes, for some weird things, this not happen, it belongs how you have configured the context, the test, etc...

May be, if you can provide more information about the concrete scenario, you can find help here.

Comment: this is not true, why would it clean the database. junit only runs test it will do nothing to the database unless you wrote it

Comment: In the context of DBunit, as the user is doing the question, yes it's how it works. It depends how you configure your test and data.